# Why isn't my og:image picture updated properly on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello all and thanks in advance for your help. Our website, Tom's Guide France has recently changed its logo.
Therefore, we updated the picture file that was linked in our og:image meta on pages not having a specific one.
Example URL : http://www.tomsguide.fr/solutions/id-2109117/desimlockage-dallas-urgent.html

The picture for the og:image meta is the following : http://m.bestofmedia.com/sfp/images/design/logos/fb/tgu_pic.jpg
For me, it's a text logo with an up/down arrow instead of the letter I.

But for Facebook, it's our old logo, with a torchlight.

I used the debugger for both those URL. 
But in both cases, Facebook keeps seeing my old logo.

Any hint ?

Best,

Gzav

Answer (score 0):

public static function resize_img($srcimg,$dest_img,$max_width=0,$max_height=0)  {

```
    $save = $dest_img;
    $src = null;
    $source_pic = $srcimg;

    $imageinfo = getimagesize($source_pic);

    //print_r($imageinfo);die;
    switch($imageinfo['mime'])
    {
     case 'image/png':
     $src = imagecreatefrompng($source_pic);
     break;
     case 'image/jpeg':
     $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_pic);
     break;
     case 'image/gif':
     $src = imagecreatefromgif($source_pic);
     break;
     case 'image/x-ms-bmp':
     $src = imagecreatefrombmp($source_pic);
     break; 
    }

      list($width,$height) = getimagesize($source_pic);

      $x_ratio = $max_width / $width;
      $y_ratio = $max_height / $height;

      if( ($width <= $max_width) && ($height <= $max_height) ){
       $tn_width = $width;
       $tn_height = $height;
      }
      elseif($y_ratio == 0){
       $tn_height = ceil($x_ratio * $height);
       $tn_width = $max_width;
      }
      elseif($x_ratio == 0){
       $tn_width = ceil($y_ratio * $width);
       $tn_height = $max_height;
      }
      elseif (($x_ratio * $height) < $max_height){
       $tn_height = ceil($x_ratio * $height);
       $tn_width = $max_width;
      }
      else{
       $tn_width = ceil($y_ratio * $width);
       $tn_height = $max_height;
      }

     // $ext = strtolower(array_pop(explode(".", $srcimg)));
       $ext=substr($srcimg,-3,3);
      //ini_set('memory_limit', '32M');

      $tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($tn_width,$tn_height);
      //print_r($tmp.$src);die;

      imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$tn_width, $tn_height,$width,$height);

      if(($ext=="jpg") || ($ext=="jpeg")) 
      { 
        $ye = imagejpeg($tmp, $save, 100) ; 
      }

      if($ext=="gif"){ imagegif($tmp, $save) ;  }
      if($ext=="bmp"){ imagebmp($tmp, $save) ;  }
      if($ext=="png"){
        //imagecolortransparent($tmp, imagecolorallocate($tmp,0,0,0));
        imagepng($tmp, $save, 9) ;
        }

}   
$this->resize_img($siurcename,$dest_img2,83,83);//calling function
```